# How to check whether my C# code is reading the file in asynchronous mode?

Tags: c#, file-io

```
public void fileReader()
{
Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.None, 30, true);
byte[] Buffer = new byte[30];
while (stream.Read(Buffer, 0, 30) > 0)
{ 
 label1.text=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer); 
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
stream.Dispose();
}
```

THIS IS MY C# CODE TO READ 30 BYTES OF DATA AT A TIME FROM A FILE. I've created the Stream with FileStream constructor having useAsync=true. Here stream.Read method is used.

1. Is this read operation working in ASYNCHRNOUS mode?
2. How to check this?
3. Another problem is that `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer);` gives white spaces as '□' character... y?
4. Is there any other way to make a 1 second delay other than `Thread.Sleep(1000);` ?

Comment: Use the `StreamReader` class; your code will break multi-byte characters.  What do you mean by asynchronous?

Comment: To read the file async you should call ReadAsync

Comment: @SLaks synchronous or asynchronous I/O.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Casperah am having .net framework 3.5 :(

Comment: In that case you should look at my answer below, I think it will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't since you are using the syncronous `Read`method

if you wish to read it asyncronous you would have to use the `BeginRead` method

Below is an example on the usage of BeginRead from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
private void ReadStreamAsyncImpl(Stream stream)
    {
        chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        stream.BeginRead(chunk, 
                         0, 
                         chunkSize, 
                         new AsyncCallback(BeginReadCallback), 
                         stream);
    }

    private void BeginReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Stream stream = ar.AsyncState as Stream;
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);
        StreamContentsAsString += StreamEncoding.GetString(chunk, 0, bytesRead);

        if (bytesRead < chunkSize) {
            // Finished
            isOperationInProgress = false;
            stream.Close();
            if (null != ReadStreamCompleted) {
                ReadStreamCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        } else {
            ReadStreamAsyncImpl(stream);
        }
    }
```

That said you should probably use a StreamReader to read the characters of the stream instead of converting them yourself.

if you are using .NET 4.5 you can use ReadAsync as below (again from `[MSDN][2]`)

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding uniencoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            string filename = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\Documents\userinputlog.txt";
            byte[] result;

```
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            result = new byte[SourceStream.Length];
            await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)SourceStream.Length);
        }

        UserInput.Text = uniencoding.GetString(result);
    }
```

Comment: NO use of having 
`Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.None, 30, **true**);` ??

Comment: @Hybridzz not if you call a method that is syncronous no

Comment: @Hybridzz the first example is pre .NET4.5

Comment: have answer for my 4th question?

Comment: YEs but whether that feasible depends on your goal

Comment: @hybridzz you didn't State The goal but there are idea posted in comments to other answers

Answer (score 1):

Reading your file like that seems to be causing you a lot of problems without solving anything.  I do not see the point of reading 30 bytes at a time and then decode the result.  You might end up decoding the last character wrong.

I recommend that you do something like this:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        String result = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        label1.Text = result;
    }
}
```

But maybe a BackgroundWorker is much easier to use, sending the line to the UI using the progress callback.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Argument as String, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, line);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) 
                return;
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.UserState as String;
}
```

Comment: actually i too dont need this way.. My assignment needs this.. :P

Comment: Hm, that is a peculiar requirement, reading 30 bytes asynchronous convert it to a UTF8 string risking an ArgumentException because a multibyte character is broken and then wait for 1 second and then read 30 more bytes.  By the way, you can wait 1 second using a Timer and continue in a timer event.